# move cursor up/down in UITextView

Tags: iphone

The only public API I found allowed me only to move the cursor right/left using selectedRange property.
Any workaround to perform that task up/down?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't found an answer, you may just have to develop your own custom component using Core Text.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty old question ... but for anyone still trying to find a way to do this:

You can count the number of \n characters up to the current range.location and set the new range.location to a \n before to the cursor up a row or to a \n after the cursor to move it down.

If you want to move it up or down and keep it in line with the characters on the row you will need to count the number of characters on each row and move it to the right location

Comment: Can you display your answer in code please? I really like it, it's just that I can't really implement it.